# Unable to change or add categories

Tags: magento-1.9, category, error, save

We're unable to change or add categories in the Magento 1 (1.9.2.2) backend. Upon clicking the 'Save category' button I get the following error in my console:

[image: error when hitting the save category button]

I've traced it back to the follwing code snippet that's located in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/category/edit/form.phtml`.

```
// Get info about what we're submitting - to properly update tree nodes
    var categoryId = params['general[id]'] ? params['general[id]'] : 0;
    var isCreating = categoryId == 0; // Separate variable is needed because '0' in javascript converts to TRUE
    var path = params['general[path]'].split('/');
    var parentId = path.pop();
    if (parentId == categoryId) { // Maybe path includes category id itself
        parentId = path.pop();
    }
```

The `params['general[path']` is empty so the `.split()` function cannot fire.

Upon inspection of the backend form that creates or changes a category I've found out that `general[path]` is missing in the code. I've compared this to another Mangento 1 installation. This is the element that's loading on a 'healthy' Magento 1 installation:

[image: misssing HTML element]

I can't seem to find out what goes wrong. This causes a serious problem because we need to be able to alter categories for SEO reasons and to push new products.